# thymeleaf template cannot load srcs in diffrent folders

Tags: html, spring, web, thymeleaf

The srcs placed in diffrent folders than the html file arent loading correcly.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you create a folder "public" at same level as templates, you can set any kind of resources, js, images, css...

Imagine you have this structure:

```
public
      js
        jquery-2.2.1.js
      css
        styles.css
templates
      index.html
```

In your templates (index.html) the proper way to use it would be

```
<script th:src="@{/js/jquery-2.2.1.js}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/style.css}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the same structure,

```html
 <img  th:src="@{/resources/assets/images/onecard-logo.png}" />
```

you follow according to your resolver 
it may work

try it